# I can't archive my swift framework because of bitcode

Tags: swift, frameworks, archive

I have made a Swift framework. It builds normally for running on a device but Xcode can't archive it because of bitcode.

So I tried to find bitcode setting but it's nowhere.

I tried to add `-fembed-bitcode` to compiler settings but it's nowhere, as well. How can I solve this problem?

I want another project that imports my framework to be able to build for both device and archive.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Select your project navigator and then search as enable bitcode. Your image shows that your target is not properly selected.

Comment: I have searched the keyword but there isn't about 'bitcode'. my project is for framework. please help me..